# How to pass and update data through custom directive with ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to add a common custom directive where when instantiated, will look through string input and returns string with proper telephone HTML a tag. Currently the logic is within message directive, where in the html I have:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages >
            <p ng-bind-html=message.title</p> 
        </div>
```

and in directive I have:

```
.directive('message', function () {
        return {
            scope: {
                messages: "=messages",
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: 'MessageSummary',
            controllerAs: 'messageSummary'
        };
    })

.controller('MessageSummary', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  angular.forEach($scope.messages, function (message, index) {
     $scope.messages[index].title = wrapStringWithPhoneNumberHTMLTag($scope.messages[index].title);
  });
```

I need to extract this logic out to its own directive so it can be reused anywhere. Currently I added:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages >
            <p ng-bind-html=message.title ng-phone-caller=message.title</p> 
        </div>
```

and

```
.directive('ngPhoneCaller',function() {
       return {
           scope: {
               inputString: '='
           },
           link: function (scope) {
               scope.inputString = wrapStringWithPhoneNumberHTMLTag(scope.inputString);
           }
       }
```

but it scope.inputString that is passed into the function is undefined. Also, I'm a bit lost on how I would integrate this with ng-bind-html-> I need this to validate the returned HTML string after its been passed into the custom common directive. Also, is this the best way of doing it? It seems like anywhere someone uses my attribute custom directive they would need to implement ng-bind-html, is there a way to integrate inject HTML safely within the custom directive?

Answer (score 0):

Basic example to use directive by passing data into the template layout

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController1', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {
      'title': 'one'
    },
    {
      'title': 'two'
    },
    {
      'title': 'three'
    }
  ];
});

app.controller('MyController2', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {
      'title': 'satu'
    },
    {
      'title': 'dua'
    },
    {
      'title': 'tiga'
    }
  ];
});

app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  'use strict';
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      data: '=data'
    },
    template: [
      '<div ng-repeat="record in data">',
        '{{ record.title }}',
      '</div>'
    ].join('')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController1">
    <my-directive data="data">
  </div>
  <br \>
  <div ng-controller="MyController2">
    <my-directive data="data">
  </div>
</div>
```